# JMS Serializer Bundle not getting xml value

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.3

I am migrating our new API to Symfony 3.3 (and getting ready for Symfony4) but I have got some problems with JMSSerializerBundle.

I have one XML that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response version="4.1" sessionId="1" type="MY_TYPE">
  <status>XXX - My status text</status>
  <period start="YYYYmmdd" end="YYYYmmdd" />
  <amount_details currencyCode="EUR">
    <nett_amount>10</nett_amount>
    <comission_amount>10</comission_amount>
    <total_amount>10</total_amount>
  </amount_details>
</response>
```

When I try to construct an object with JMSSerializerBundle I get all values ok but one: "amount_details".

this is my yaml reference:

```
App\Domain\DTO\PrebookResponseProvider:
    properties:
        status:
            type: string

        period:
            type: App\Domain\Provider\DataTransferObject\Period               

        amountDetails:
            type: App\Domain\Provider\DataTransferObject\AmountDetails
            serialized_name: amount_details
```

That DTO is as simple as it seems:

```
    class PrebookResponseProvider
    {
        /** @var  string $status */
        protected $status;          

        /** @var  Period $period */
        protected $period;            

        /**
         * @var  AmountDetails $amountDetails
         */
        protected $amountDetails;

       //GETTERS AND SETTERS GOT HERE
   }
```

And the jms_serializer.yaml:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: false
        directories:
            Entities:
                path: '%kernel.root_dir%/Infrastructure/Resources/config/serializer'
    expression_evaluator:
        id: jms_serializer.expression_evaluator
```

I have tried everything I know, but still get `amount_details` as null when working with DTO.

Any idea?

Comment: Just checking but you're missing a > at the end of "<total_amount>10</total_amoun"

Comment: Corrected, it was just a typo error (copy and paste). Received XML is all ok (and working on old API version).

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but next thing I see is two m's in AmmountDetails class name, is that correct?

Comment: :-D just misspelled, we are not english talking programmers. It is, but it does not affect code. Anyway, fixing it.